# Getting array instead of string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have tried everything but answer is probably much simple. Variable `$data['phone']` is for example `954a23589` and I want only numbers so ill get them.

```
$phoneW = strval($data['phone']);
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $phoneW, $matches);
print_r(array_values($matches));  echo '<br /><br />';
```

The output is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 954 [1] => 23589 ) )
```

I want everyone of them together as string or int (does not matter).

Comment: print_r(implode('', array_values($matches)));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably easier to replace every non-digit with an empty string:

```
$number = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $phoneW);
```

Comment: ..and then use `intval($string)` or `(int)$string` to cast it to an integer if needed.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: you cannot cast phone numbers to int, since phone numbers are normally long numbers and will probably be larger than `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: and sometimes contain leading zeroes that must not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

> and I want only numbers so ill get them

Why not replace everything that *is not* a digit with “nothing”?

```
echo preg_replace('#[^\d]#', '', '954a23589');
```